# Safari doesn't respect overflow: hidden in conjunction with transform?

Tags: html, css, safari, overflow, css-transforms

The following HTML causes all kinds of crazy on Safari (at least 15+). First, the text contained within a child div of an `overflow: hidden` div is not clipped to the div's boundary. Second, scrolling the page reveals parts of the properly clipped child image!

Chrome and Firefox behave as expected (run the code snipped to see).

Removing the `transform` from the containing div fixes the scrolling issue but not the text clipping. I'm animating these elements and want to continue using `transform`. Any ideas on what Safari is thinking or for workarounds?

UPDATE: Adding `will-change: transform` to the `#slide` div or the child div containing the text fixes the clipping problem. Why and does this point to a better solution?

```html
<body style="margin: 0">
  <div style="width: 1280px; height: 500px; overflow: auto">
    <div id="slide" style="transform: scale(1); width: 375px; height: 2134px; overflow: hidden">
      <div style="position: absolute; width: 900px; height: 100px; font-size: 80px">
        this text should be clipped
      </div>
      <img
        src="http://next.playful.software/_/api/resources/-Mrhhc4W1jBhv-cffL0v/data/sha256:5815fbb5eee544606c43ad5f7fba7612f4c7eae3e4456741a7ae23dd493f1de9"
        style="width: 1599px; height: 2134px"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do all of the styles have to be inline?

Comment: @Kameron Not if moving them to classes would help resolve the issues!

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `overflow-x: hidden` it should be fine. For Safari, specifying which axis should it should hide will work when using `transform`

```html
<body style="margin: 0">
  <div style="width: 1280px; height: 500px; overflow: auto">
    <div id="slide" style="transform: scale(1); width: 375px; height: 2134px; position: relative; overflow-x: hidden">
      <div style="position: absolute; width: 900px; height: 100px; font-size: 80px">
        this text should be clipped
      </div>
      <img
        src="http://next.playful.software/_/api/resources/-Mrhhc4W1jBhv-cffL0v/data/sha256:5815fbb5eee544606c43ad5f7fba7612f4c7eae3e4456741a7ae23dd493f1de9"
        style="width: 1599px; height: 2134px"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `transformZ` is not a thing so adding it effectively removes the `transform`. As stated I want to use `transform` for animation.

Comment: @darrinm See the adjusted. Specifying `overflow-x: hidden;` fixed it.

Comment: @darrinm did this work for you also?

Comment: I appreciate the effort but it does not work. The vertical scrolling behaves wrong (on Chrome as well as Safari). At first mouse-wheel it does some elastic movement but does not scroll. A second mouse-wheel movement makes it scroll. After it stops it takes two attempts to scroll again.

Comment: @darrinm Interesting, I don't see the chrome issues you're referring to. They seem to be acting the same for me (both mine and your snippets). For me, it runs the exact same in Safari, but the overflow scroll bar is not showing up on Safari.